# When saving HTML file, Spring Boot only to reload that file, and keep project running.

Tags: html, spring-boot

I would like to when ever I save my front-end resources, to have Spring Boot keep running and not have to rebuild and run project every time.

Example, coding my front-end in Atom, when I save and test in browser, its reloaded in the Spring project, and I don't have to re-run my Spring application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use spring-boot-devtools. See official documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html)

**Update**

Set addResources in spring-boot-maven-plugin to **true**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <addResources>true</addResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then run the application with **mvn spring-boot:run**

> You will still need to refresh the broswer to see the changes. If you want live reload you can try http://livereload.com/extensions/

Comment: Yes rad the documentation, and have implemented it, but still doesnt work.

https://github.com/ThierryLucDenichaud/SpringBoot_SQL_HTML.git

can see here

Comment: How do you start the application?

Comment: I just run my Main Application as a Java application